# msgraph teams api, filter for groups only with teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have a requirement to filter for teams which have a given string.  To achieve that I found the following documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-list-all-teams.  I cannot use the beta APIs, so the only option left for me as per this is to

1. Get all the teams using `/groups?$select=id,resourceProvisioningOptions`
2. Manually do the filtering

I am a bit worried that this could overload the server since I am loading a lot of data and then filtering, is there a better way to do this?

Also I tried the following curl command `curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer token" -X GET "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$select=id,resourceProvisioningOptions" -k` but this returns all the fields like `expirationDateTime, displayName` and so on.  Am I doing something wrong in this curl command

Comment: Hi @tmpdev - Could you please explain are you want to list all teams in an organization (tenant) or Get the teams in Microsoft Teams that you are a direct member of. Also explain which exactly data you want to filter from the teams?

Comment: hi @Mamatha-MSFT I want to list all teams in a tenant (organization) which contains a given string.  For example if my search string is `abc` I want all the teams in the organization which contain the given string in its name, for example `abc1`, `team abc1`, `myabc team`

Answer (score 0):

Please check below curl command

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$select=id,resourceProvisioningOptions,displayName&$filter=startswith(displayName,%27abc%27)' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer token'
```

Comment: @tmpdev - Please let us know does that help clarify?